# How to configure Ambari to send SNMP notification

Tags: notifications, ambari

How can I sent SNMP notification in Ambari, I have read [this](http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/Ambari-2.2.1.1/bk_Ambari_Users_Guide/content/_configuring_notifications.html) and do the required configuration, but when I use this command: `nohup snmptrapd -m ALL -A -n -Lf /traps.log &` to see notification I don't find any thing in the log file ( except the version of snmp).
thank you in advance for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for those who face the same problem, I solve it by following this [tutorial](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/74370/snmp-alert.html) :